# How to cite information obtained from Google Maps Area Calculator Tool?

Tags: citations, technology

In my research, I measured an area with the aid of Google Maps Area Calculator Tool.

How should I site the information I have obtained. And what should I include? Should I include a screen-shot of it? Does the app let us export a picture of the area we want? Can I cite it with software like EndNote?

Comment: For this kind of information, it is practical to put the website in the footnote.

Comment: http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/08/how-to-cite-online-maps.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues.  First, you need to comply with the google terms of Use agreement.  For maps, information is available at https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html

Next, you want your readers to be able to find the maps you're referring to.  Use the "share or embed" option on the maps page to generate a permalink.

Lastly, what should the reference look like?  APA provides some guidance at http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/08/how-to-cite-online-maps.html

For one example they show

> Google. (n.d.). [Google Maps directions for driving from Ingolstadt,
>   Germany, to Geneva, Switzerland]. Retrieved August 4, 2015, from [url
>   here]

I would change the author as specified in Google's attribution guidelines above, and I would replace "driving directions for ...." to "Area Calculator" or some such.

After doing this, I'd let the editorial process take over, having done your due diligence.